# to change date from string to date type in hive

Tags: hive

I want to change string which is in format `dd/mm/yyyy` to date type in hive.

I am using hive version 1.0.0 . I have tried using:

```
TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('07/03/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy')))
```

But it returns `NULL`. Although it works with format `'dd-mm-yyyy'`. But it returns NULL with `'dd/mm/yyyy'`.

I have tried using `CAST` also but it also does not give me the correct result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
M - month
m - minutes
```

---

```
hive> select TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('07/03/2013', 'dd/MM/yyyy'))) ;
OK
2013-03-07
```

or

```
hive> select TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('07/03/2013', 'd/M/y'))) ;
OK
2013-03-07
```

or

```
hive> select cast (regexp_replace('07/03/2013','(..)/(..)/(....)','$3-$2-$1') as date);
OK
2013-03-07
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try two options:

1. Check if simple replace works:

> TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(replace('07/03/2013', '/', '-'), 'dd-MM-yyyy')))

2. Take a look at [date documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) to check if any function will work for you